# Get value from localStorage to use in popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating my first chrome extension and have gotten to a stage I can't seem to figure out.

Basically I can get my option to save, but I don't know how to retrieve the value to use it in popup.html

Here's my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "My Extension",
"options_page": "options.html",

"permissions": [
      "storage"
    ],

"description": "My Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
   }
}
```

**options.js**

```
// Save options to localStorage.
function save_options()
{
  localStorage["url"] = document.getElementById("url").value;

  // Let the user know the options were saved.
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  status.innerHTML = "Saved OK";
  setTimeout( function() { status.innerHTML = ""; }, 5000 );
}

// Populate options from from localStorage.
function load_options()
{
  var url = localStorage["url"];
  if (url == null) { url = ""; }
  document.getElementById("url").value = url;
}

// call load_options top populate the GUI when the DOM has loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load_options);

// call save_options when the user clicks the save button
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener('click', save_options);
```

**options.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<head><title>My Options</title></head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <label for="url">
            <p>My URL</p>
            <input type="text" id="url" />
            <button id="save">Save</button>
        </label>

    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>

</body>
<script src="options.js"></script>
</html>
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="myURL" id="myURL" name="myURL" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine, and in options you can save anything you put into the url field. Now I want to get that saved value and make it be the src (myURL) for the iframe in popup.html

Example: So in options if you entered and saved http://www.google.com then in the popup.html the iframe would be:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" id="myURL" name="myURL" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic question, but there you go.

1. Obviously, to do this you need JavaScript code. Chrome's Content Security Policy forbids inline code, so the code must go into a separate `.js` file (say, `popup.js`) and included in the HTML:

   ```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <iframe id="myURL" name="myURL" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
      </body>
    </html>
   ```
2. The code should:

a. Read the value from `localStroage`

b. Find the element on the page

c. Assign its `src` property.

```
    // Read the value
    var url = localStorage.url;
      // or = localStorage["url"];
      // or = localStorage.get("url");
    
    // Find the element  
    var element = document.getElementById("myUrl");

    // Assign the property
    element.src = url;
     // or .setAttribute("src", url);
```

Of course, all of this can be compressed in a single line of code by removing the temp variables `url` and `element` (see below).

3. There is a problem with this, however. The code will execute when the `<script>` element is read - before the `#myURL` element is read. Therefore, it will fail, as `element` will not be found and will be undefined.

There are two ways to fix it:

a. Move the `<script>` tag below the element it refers to, like you did in `options.html`

b. Wrap your code in a listener for an event that page is fully parsed and ready for it. I prefer this solution.

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      document.getElementById("myUrl").src = localStorage.url;
    });
```

Further reading:

- [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)
- HTML [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)
- An alternative: [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: Perfect thanks! Works like a charm. There's just one more thing if you don't mind. The line in options.js says `if (url == null) { url = ""; }` if I change it to `if (url == null) { url = "no-page.html"; }` and I don't have a URL set in my options, it doesn't load `no-page.html` and element inspectors says `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` yet the file does exist. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

To get the local storage value you can do

```
savedURL = localStorage.get('url') ;
```

and then in jQuery it is like this

```
$('#myURL').attr('src',savedURL)
```

Comment: What if I'm not using jQuery?

Comment: @user3256143 Just a comment, but you can always switch to using jquery: being local, there's no bandwidth/responsiveness downside in including it.

Comment: document.getElementById("myUrl").setAttribute('src',savedURL);